# Sending a mail with Javascript in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I design a contact form using html & upload it my server under my domain name. Now I want to get mail from site user.
[my contact form design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAP1n.png)

Comment: You have to insert the mail to your database and select it whenever you want it. You put the data with the AJAX. What did you try? You haven't put any code.

Comment: drop some code so we can help you

Comment: Show us what have you tried yet

Comment: Please show some code for what you've tried so far. To complete this you will need to use a server side script to send the emails, not a client side script like javascript. You can you JS to call it though through AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can go about this, you can firstly use aJax with a POST to the database (jQuery) or you can interact with a controller by posting to the controller and then handling the sql queries within the controller.

You cannot use javascript on it's own to send mail, it's clientside code.. You can code a controller which will send mail when you post your details captured from your contact form.

Please post your attempts so I can assist you further.